# Trying to append html to 'td's with multiple tables. What selector should I use?

Tags: jquery, html

So here is my problem. I have two table's on my webpage, I am building a sudoku game. The table i want to access is a class called 'game' its a class. It has 81 td's and each one has a data attribute called squre. I want to loop through the td elements and append each one of the integers in the array. What I cant figure out is the correct selector to use to grab all the td's, without affecting my other table.
Any Help is greatly appericated - Thanks in advance

```
var array = [4,3,8,9,5,1,2,7,7,1,2,3,6,4,5,8,9,5,8,9,7,1,2,3,6,4,5,8,4,7,1,9,3,6,2,2,3,6,4,5,8,9,7,1,9,7,1,2,3,6,4,5,8,9,7,8,2,3,1,4,5,6,6,4,5,8,9,7,1,2,3,1,2,3,6,4,5,8,9,7]; 
var game_start = function(button, array){ 
button.click(function(){
console.log('clicked');
 $(".table > td").each(function(e){
  console.log('preparing for loop')
  for(i = 0; i <= array.length -1; i++){
    $(e.target).html = array[i];
    console.log(array[i]);
  }
 })
})
}
```

Comment: And your representative HTML would be what, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is

```
$('.game td')
```

Then use this on your jQuery elements to get the data attribute:

```
$(element).data("square");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to target both tables, then give the table you want to select an ID, or even just a unique class.

```
 <table id="table1" class="table"> ... </table>
 <table id="table2" class="table"> ... </table>
```

And use `$('#table1')`

As you've explained it, you're currently getting both tables with your selector.